# Optimize magento performance

Tags: php, magento

I am following this guide to optimize the YSlow Grade.

http://aciddrop.com/2008/01/21/boost-your-website-load-time-with-3-lines-of-code/

I checked in magento the hints and the first file that its executed is 3colums.phtml of my special template

So after the  I put this

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php_speedy_wp/libs/php_speedy/controller/class.compressor.php');  ?>
<?php $compressor = new compressor('css,javascript,page'); ?>
<?php $compressor->start(); ?> 4
```

and before the body I put this

```
<?php $compressor->finish(); ?>
```

However I get this error
Fatal error: main() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/theprint/public_html/php_speedy_wp/libs/php_speedy/controller/class.compressor.php' (include_path='/home/theprint/public_html/lib/minify/lib:/home/theprint/public_html/app/code/local:/home/theprint/public_html/app/code/community:/home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core:/home/theprint/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/theprint/public_html/app/design/frontend/depot/default/template/page/3columns.phtml on line 158
How can I fix that?

Comment: I failed to run the installer script, lol, however after I did this I still got errors like this one: trict Notice: Redefining already defined constructor for class JSMin  in /home/theprint/public_html/php_speedy_wp/libs/php_speedy/libs/php/jsmin.php on line 167

Trace:
#0 /home/theprint/public_html/php_speedy_wp/libs/php_speedy/php_speedy.php(70): mageCoreErrorHandler(2048, 'Redefining alre...', '/home/theprint/...', 167, Array)
#1 /home/theprint/public_html/php_speedy_wp/libs/php_speedy/php_speedy.php(70): require_once()

Comment: @whoever that voted -1, post a reason.

Comment: Your question is actually missing a question :(

Comment: you have to read well, the question is how to fix that exception. ITS OBVIOUS THAT IS THE QUESTION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that PHP Speedy doesn't do anything that isn't done by [Fooman's Speedster](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/457/fooman-speedster/), and Speedster is made for Magento and proven to work well with it. Save yourself the effort of dealing with errors by leaving PHP Speedy entirely.

Comment: thats a nice extension, I already gave it a try and does its job well.

Answer (score 1):

I recently attend a webinar (Performance Matters by PINT) that gave this extension an option as well.

http://www.nitrogento.com/

It appears to allows minify the CSS and JS like the extension above but also adds the below.

Full Page Cache for Community Edition
Bloc caching of 8 new entries (footer, etc.)
Custom bloc cache:put your block in cache
Auto Sprite & theme patching
Auto deployment of CDN & theme patching
Minify & Compression of JS and CSS
Htaccess settings (activate browser cache)

I would like to state that the most common improvements for Magento are from MySQL configuration from my perspective.  I am using Magento 1.5.0.1 with more than 250k, to store with 1.5m, only counting the frontend visible ones. and I am using simple and grouped items so you probably estimate the total number.  Det

APC/Memcached can create great improvements by allowing your PHP variables to be stored as well.  This will lower you Time to First Byte.

You can also leverage CSS sprites, to lower your HTTP calls.

Apache modules like mod_headers, mod_deflate, and mod_expires, can help quite a bit too.